# Clone CloudSQL Instance to different location

Tags: mysql, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I need to clone a CloudSQL (MySQL) instance from one location to another.
It will move from Frankfurt to London, is this possible?
I know I can only clone from GCP dashboard in the same location so I hope I can achieve this another way without having to export the database and import on a new  instance.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the **"gcloud sql instances clone SOURCE DESTINATION**" Command clones one SQL instance. When you clone a Cloud SQL instance, all the instance configuration settings are copied to the clone, the [region included](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/clone-instance) and it's not possible to change the region to another one, nevertheless, I found this [**Public Issue Tracker**](https://issuetracker.google.com/74766720I) that is asking to edit the Cloud SQL instance region or move the instance to another region. I recommend that you start the request so that you can follow up on it later.

Unfortunately :(, I think that the only solution is to create a backup of your instance and restore it to an instance in another region.